# Extracting only required fields from a large XML using Java

Tags: java, jaxb, jibx

I am new to XML binding.
I have a huge XML file and I am intrested in about 10-12 elements in this file.
I have looked at JAXB, JiBX and other binding options to automate the process of extracting only the required elements. But so far I find that I need to map all the elements in the XML.
Is there a workaround. I do not want to use in memory parser like SAX or DOM. (I can but that is the last option).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Internally, JAXB also uses SAX, so why do you think that SAX is a bad choice?

Comment: Is the data you care about grouped together, or scattered around the document?

Comment: I don't think you want 'binding' at all, just to extract some data.  How big is 'huge'?

Comment: @LukasI belive SAX requires me to hardcode the XPATH to the node I want to extract. JAXB also may require XPATH, but it can be moved into a external mapping file.

Comment: @Blaise, yes the data is grouped together. I was hoping there could be some work around in JAXB which will allow me to bind the required portion of the xml and ignore the rest.

Comment: The following should help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html

Comment: @Blaise,Thank you, this might be just what I am looking for.